# UNIX: Submit job only after previous job completes?

Tags: shell-script, job-control

I would like to submit the same .sas job iterating over an argument, but I would like job only to be submitted after the previous is completed. Here is my attempt:

```
    #!/bin/ksh

    export weeks="1 2 3"
    for week in $weeks
    do

    sas -log job$week.log job.sas > /dev/null & pid_ind=$!
    wait $pid_ind

    echo "job complete for week $week"
    done
```

This results in all the jobs being submitted almost at once, and then they sit in the queue. Can anyone elaborate on the 'wait' command? I am trying to hold off submission until the previous SAS job was *completed*, not submitted.

Answer (score 4):

You have a mistake, for loop terminated with `done` keyword, not `fi`.

```
for variable in lists
do
    # do something here
done
```

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, not an answer.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeGravel: The OP had changed the question.

Comment: Ok, I understand.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "wait" command, there is no use for it. Aslo, remove the "& pid_ind=$!" This code puts the job into a background process that cause the problem you are experiencing.

Outside of daemon processes (and processes launched in background), commands within a script are synchronous. Each commands waits for the last one to finish.

```
#!/bin/ksh

weeks="3 4 5"
echo "Waiting for first job to complete..."
for week in $weeks; do
    sas -log job$week.log job.sas > /dev/null
    echo "job complete for week $week"
done
```

Comment: I've just noticed that you use /bin/ksh, I don't know how ksh behave but you should give it a try in both shells to be sure.

Comment: This is essentially what I have now, a sas job and then a sleep statement that exceeds the typical runtime of the job. This is an inefficient use of time that I'd like to tighten up.

Comment: Ok, I got it, you use the & to put the job in the background, just do that command line, removing everything after "&":

    sas -log job$week.log job.sas > /dev/null

Comment: I updated my answer removing the "&" and following portion. This syntax should work as you expected now.

Comment: This is a completely different question than the one I've submitted this answer on. @mkemp6 If your goal is to execute each jobs one by one sequentially this is the right answer. On the other hand, if you want to ask a question about how the wait command works, you shoud post another question.